# редактирование config.php

Tags: php

Я учусь делать сайты.
Есть вопрос - как сделать, чтобы можно было в админ-панели редактировать строки из `config.php`?

Comment: Хранить настройки в БД. А если в файле - то в каком-нибудь '.ini'.

Comment: config создаётся не для записи, но для чтения данных из него. Если перед вами стоит задача манипулировать данными конфига туда/сюда, создавайте в базе таблицу settings и пишите туда. В общем случае файл конфига должен быть закрыт от изменения.